# How do I design my tables to allow for a massive number of rows?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm working on a website that, boiled down, will work for the end user as a glorified to-do list. SQL is where I have the least experience I need for doing this well. Ignoring whether or not in reality, this will actually get a user base that massive, how could I design for the scenario that I have tens of thousands or more people adding dozens of their own items to this table?

Here's the layout I currently have planned for the
Items table:
ItemID | UserID| Content | Subcontent | Parent | Hierarchy | Days | Note | Alert | Deadline

So, the items created by each user are contained in that table, to be queried using something like "SELECT * WHERE UserID = $thisUser", then placed on the page and handled correctly using the other information from that row.

With this layout, would hundreds of thousands or millions of entries become a serious performance problem? If you have any suggestions or resources that you think would be helpful, I would appreciate them. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you index the column user_id, some hundred thousand or a few million should be no big problem. If we speak of even more rows, maybe several ten or hundred million, you should think of a way to evenly distribute the items according to their users. However, the row count is only one aspect influencing the performance. The moddeling of your data and the code, which queries your database, are likely to have more impact.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to rethink your database layout. Rarely are individual users going to use the same content. I think you should have a table for each user then it would be UerID|ItemID|Content|Subcontent....
This allows you to maintain your database when a user quits.